# Centering Overlay Widget Instance over Grid Layout

Tags: qooxdoo

I have a Composite using Grid Layout ( `qx.ui.layout.Grid` ).

However, I have to overlay an image over Grid Layout.

I managed to do it by : (`c` is the Composite, while `this` is Application )

```
c.setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.Grid());
var img = new qx.ui.basic.Image("myproject/test.png");
this.getRoot().add(img, {left: 500, top: 10});
```

The image is overlayed over Grid Layout successfully. However, I want the image centering at the center of the screen ( X-axis only , Y-axis is still required to be 10px from the top ), given that the Application occupies whole browser screen.

Tried :

- `{left: 50%}` , can't run
- `{margin: auto}`, the image disappears

How can I make the changes ?

Comment: Did you try `this.getRoot().add(img, {left: "50%", top: 10});`?

Comment: *facepalm* I misssed the quotes around the percentage. `{left: "50%"}` Almost working. I should minus half of the width of my image, but how can I do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to your question in the comments (for better `code example` rendering):

```
...
var imgWidth = qx.util.ResourceManager.getInstance().getImageWidth("myproject/test.png");
var imgWidthPercentage = imgWidth/qx.bom.Viewport.getWidth()*100;
this.getRoot().add(img, {left: (50-imgWidthPercentage)+"%", top: 10});
```